# Union of checkpointed RDD in Apache Spark has long (> 10 hour) between-stage latency

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, apache-spark, rdd

I'm implementing one of my machine learning/graph analysis algorithm on Apache Spark:

The algorithm is very iterative (like all other ML algorithms), but it has a rather strange workflow: first a subset of all training data (called seeds RDD: {S_1} is randomly selected) and loaded, in each iteration, the seeds {S_n} will update itself {S_n+1} and yield a model RDD: {M_n}. After the seeds have reached a condition the iteration will stop and all model RDD are aggregated to yield the final result.

Like all iterative implementation in MLLib, both {S_*} and {M_*} has to be checkpointed regularly (which seems to be more efficient than commiting {M} into a growing RDD and cache/checkpoint it: old data already on HDFS don't have to be written into disk again or take memory space until the final stage).

However, before the final step when all {M_*} are aggregated. The spark seems to get frozen: all stages/jobs are completed, no new stage/job are pending, and all drivers and clusters are running but doing nothing (the algorithm is still far from completion).

I have to wait for 10+ hours before it start to proceed. So the latency between stages on UI looks really weird (see the sharp contrast between 15s task running time and 10h+ between-stage latency?):

[image: Sharp contrast between 15s task running time and 10h+ between-stage latency]

I wonder if my implementation for algorithm is not optimized for Spark? Or I simply encounter a hidden issue? Thanks a lot for your opinion